# Vertica database temporary table

Tags: sql, temp-tables, vertica

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG1 (data1 VARCHAR, data2 VARCHAR,data3 VARCHAR,data4 VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO  DOMAINS_FLAG1
SELECT country,customer,phone_number,count(phone_number) from table1 
where  CAST(create_dt as DATE) = CURRENT_DATE-1
and status='COMPLETED' and ac_tion ='CHARGE' 
GROUP BY country,customer,phone_number;
SELECT * FROM DOMAINS_FLAG1;
```

i tried to create a temprory table and insert some data into the temp table using select statement,but it seems like not working.

result i get you can see from screenshot below.
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSxbT.png)

> updated rows = 0
>   but query below give me 169919 result

```
SELECT country,customer,phone_number,count(phone_number) from table1 
where  CAST(create_dt as DATE) = CURRENT_DATE-1
and status='COMPLETED' and ac_tion ='CHARGE'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection is probably set up with AUTOCOMMIT.

On Commit, by default, a temp table loses its rows.

Check the Vertica documentation:

You need to add the ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG1 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS as ， added **ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS** ,result return is same.

Comment: Well, then your query does not return any rows. Try to do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( <your_complete_SELECT_statement>) AS foo;`. It will probably return 0.

Comment: You did run a SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DOMAINS_FLAG1;  afterwards, did you?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `create table as`?

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG1 as
SELECT country, customer, phone_number, count(phone_number) as cnt
FROM table1 
WHERE CAST(create_dt as DATE) = CURRENT_DATE-1 AND
      status = 'COMPLETED' AND ac_tion = 'CHARGE' 
GROUP BY country, customer, phone_number;

SELECT * FROM DOMAINS_FLAG1;
```